# Override Pending Transition not working on android n

Tags: android-studio, animation, android-7.0-nougat

Im finishing my activity with an animation and before android n, they worked fine but now the activity just disappears without the transition. Is this a bug or something?

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    //Worked before android n
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
}
```

Comment: Did you found a resolve to this?